# Need help creating a function for certain task

Tags: swift

so i'm gonna create an app that generates recipes by reading the ingredients you entered in the app. 
For example, (i'm thinking of using arrays to do this) let's say the user pushed the buttons for these ingredients: [eggs , flour, sugar, baking soda]

and there are 3 recipes available in the app:

A - requires  eggs, flour, sugar. 
    B - requires  eggs, flour.
      C - requires  baking soda, tomato sauce.

The function i would like to create would choose recipes A and B because the user has the required ingredients, unlike for recipe C, where he is missing the sauce.

I think the way of doing it is by comparing the ingredients list and recipe lists, and if both have the same items or the recipe has less ingredients, than the app displays the recipes.
What function can I use to go about doing this?

Comment: I don't see a single question mark in this post.  What's the question?

Comment: trying to find a function to compare 2 lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSSet` would work nicely for you.  It has a method `isSubsetOfSet` that tests if one set is a subset of another.

```
let recipes:[String:NSSet] = ["A": NSSet(objects: "eggs", "flour", "sugar"), "B": NSSet(objects: "eggs", "flour"), "C": NSSet(objects: "baking soda", "tomato sauce")]

let ingredients = NSSet(objects: "eggs", "flour", "sugar", "baking soda")

for (name, recipe) in recipes {
    if recipe.isSubsetOfSet(ingredients) {
        println("you have the ingredients for recipe \(name)")
    }
}
```

If you want to build up your `ingredients` set bit by bit, then use an `NSMutableSet`:

```
var ingredients = NSMutableSet()
ingredients.addObject("flour")
ingredients.addObject("butter")
```

Comment: Thanks! But how do I add an object to the set? For example, I want it to start out empty: var ingredients = NSSet(objects: ""), then, when i click for example, the egss button, it adds eggs to the list. I tried: ingredients.addObject("eggs") but that didnt work

Comment: Thanks a lot! Still have to get used to sets though!